# Transmission data of two Datagridviews

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two data gridviews. `Datagridview1` has two columns (has data). `Datagridview2` is blank

Each time I press the button `Value`, I want to get all values of columns 2 of `Datagridview1` and add to columns of `Datagridview2`.

Each time I press the `Value` button then add one more column in Datagridview 2 but with data not sent to new column. Data was to be added to new row of old column (Datagridview 2).

I want to data has sent to new column of Datagridview 2.

Thanks to everyone!

```
private void btnValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //dtgBangketqua datagridview 1
    //dgvBKQChung datagridview 2
    dgvBKQChung.Columns.Add("DanhGia", "Đánh Giá Lần" + (i+1));

    foreach (DataGridViewRow RowinBangKetQua in dtgBangketqua.Rows)
    {
        string strDiem = RowinBangKetQua.Cells[3].Value as string;
        dgvBKQChung.Rows.Add(strDiem);
    }

    i++;
    dtgBangketqua.Rows.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me? :(

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what you want because of the poor grammar above.  If I understand you correctly you want to copy the 2 existing columns in DGV1 to DGV2 on the first click of `Value` button.  Then any click after that you want to add another blank column to DGV2?

Comment: When i click the    value button, column in DGV1 is copied to DGV2. But data was not copied to new column, it was copied to new row of old column (DGV2).